# Iterate and assign value in Pandas dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

I have a pandas dataframe composed of 8 columns (`c1` to `c7` and the last is called `total`). `c1` to `c7` are `0` and `1`.

The column total should be an assignment for the maximum number of 1 in a sequence within `c1` to `c7`. `c1` to `c7` represent weekdays, hence 7 should then flip to 1.

For example, if we would have and initial dataframe like df:

```
| c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 | c6 | c7 | total |
|:---|:---|:---|: --|:---|:---|:---|:-----:|
| 1  | 1  | 1  | 1  | 1  | 0  | 0  |  0    |
| 0  | 0  | 1  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  |  0    |
| 1  | 1  | 0  | 1  | 1  | 0  | 0  |  0    |
| 1  | 1  | 1  | 0  | 1  | 1  | 1  |  0    |
| 1  | 0  | 1  | 1  | 1  | 0  | 1  |  0    |
| 1  | 0  | 1  | 0  | 1  | 0  | 1  |  0    |
| 0  | 1  | 0  | 1  | 0  | 1  | 0  |  0    |
```

My initial thought was to create a loop with an if statement within to evaluate the criteria within the columns and assign the value to the column total.

```
i = "c1"
d = 
for i in df.iloc[:,0:7]:
    if df[i] == 1 and df[i-1] == 1:
    df["total"]:= df["total"] + 1
```

I would expect df to look like:

```
| c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 | c6 | c7 | total |
|:---|:---|:---|: --|:---|:---|:---|:-----:|
| 1  | 1  | 1  | 1  | 1  | 0  | 0  |  5    |
| 0  | 0  | 1  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  |  1    |
| 1  | 1  | 0  | 1  | 1  | 0  | 0  |  2    |
| 1  | 1  | 1  | 0  | 1  | 1  | 1  |  6    |
| 1  | 0  | 1  | 1  | 1  | 0  | 1  |  3    |
| 1  | 0  | 1  | 0  | 1  | 0  | 1  |  2    |
| 0  | 1  | 0  | 1  | 0  | 1  | 0  |  1    |
```

I haven't been able to get to a result, was trying to build step by step but kept getting an error in the if statement evaluation

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Should not the expected result of the last row be 1 ? If it is 2 can you explain why ?

Comment: Yes, my apologies, it is 1 indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[ 1,1,1,1,1,0,0], [0,0,1,0,0,0,0],[1,1,0,1,1,0,0]])

def fun(x):
    count = 0; 
    result = 0; 
    n = len(x)
    for i in range(0,2*n):
        if x[i % n] == 0:
            result = max(result, count)
            count = 0
        else:
            count += 1
    return result

df['total'] = df.apply(lambda x: fun(x), axis=1)
```

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   total
0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   5
1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1
2   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   2
```

### Bugs in your loop

1. `df[i-1]` when i==0 will throw an error
2. `df[i]` gives the values of ith column of all the rows
3. `7 should then flip to 1`: This part is missing in your code

To flip the tail (7) of the row back to head(1), place a copy of row at the tail and then check for constitutive 1's. This can also be done by looping the row twice and using a modulus operator. Check this [algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-consecutive-ones-or-zeros-in-a-binary-circular-array/) for more details